# How to retrieve last saved Domain Class in Grails

Tags: grails

I have a Domain Class called TimeEvent which can have one of two types (properties in TimeEvent as enums) START or STOP. When storing a Domain Class of type START I first want to check the last saved TimeEvent to see if I have to first store a STOP TimeEvent.

The problem is that I have not yet been able to find how to retrieve the last saved TimeEvent. Are there any top or last methods I could use?

Answer (score 4):

Add a [dateCreated](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.x/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) property to the TimeEvent domain class and fetch the last row like this:

```
def lastEvent = TimeEvent.list([max:1,sort:"dateCreated",order:"desc"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have 3 options:

1) as Olav said: add the dateCreated property

2) make TimeEvent.list().last()  <- this give you the last object of the list

3) If you need to audit all your classes (not only TimeEvent) you should think about using Hibernate Envers for Auditing Classes

Comment: or TimeEvent.list([max:1,sort:"id",order:"desc"] <-- you will get the last too